# Why 'begin' keyword for if statement, is showing error in stored procedure. (mysql)?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
begin
declare currentMonth int;
declare half int default 0;
set currentMonth = (select DATE_FORMAT(now(),"%m"));
if(currentMonth > 5)
    **begin**
        set half = 1
    end
```

`end;`

[This is screen shot of what error is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPZUr.png)

> Showing me this error: MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'begin set half = 1; end select currentMonth into half' at line 6

Comment: mysql if does not require `begin` its `if <condition> then <logic> end if;`

Comment: Did you try looking at the MySQL documentation : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html

Comment: its stored procedure and most links told me that syntax

Comment: yeah it worked with   'then'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `into` in select set is not uset

```
begin

declare currentMonth int;
declare half int default 0;

select DATE_FORMAT(now(),"%m") INTO @currentMonth;

if(currentMonth > 5) THEN
        set half = 1;
end if;

end
```

Comment: begin should be used only when you are declaring a variable.
and you semicolon missing after set half=1;